# Imagem não exibe no mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Não estou conseguindo colocar a logo no cabeçalho do mpdf.

Não exibe e não mostra nenhum erro...

O PDF gera, com o texto, mas sem a logo.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->showImageErrors = true;
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('
<div style="text-align: left;><img src="https://sistema.site.com.br/uploads/logo/logo.jpg" height="42"></div>
');
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter('
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="33%">{DATE d-m-Y}</td>
        <td width="33%" align="center">{PAGENO}/{nbpg}</td>
        <td width="33%" style="text-align: right;">My document</td>
    </tr>
</table>');
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
//$css = file_get_contents("css/estilo.css");
//$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();

exit;
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podem ser duas coisas:

A URL `https://sistema.site.com.br/uploads/logo/logo.jpg` dá erro `404` (URL não existe no servidor) ou você não fechou o atributo style com as aspas:

```
style="text-align: left;
                        ↑
                falta aspas aqui
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso...rsrs, faltou o fechamento das `"`